# I am unable to assign my AJAX response to my divs

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following JS code:

```html
var b=0;
function Fetch_Comments() {
    var comment=document.getElementsByClassName("comnt_list");
    for (i=0; i<comment.length; i++) {
        var post_id1=comment[i].getAttribute("data-flag2");
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST',"../OOP/AJAX-Response.php",true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("post_id1="+post_id1);
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(comment.item(1));
         comment.item(0) = xhr.responseText;
        }
        b++;
    }    
}
```

I want to assign the response text to to my divs but it always returns an error:

> (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null)

What is the issue? Kindly help.

Comment: what do you mean by `comment.item(0)=xhr.responseText` it will give the error `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`

Comment: The error references innerHTML, but you never access it. Perhaps you meant `comment.item(0).innerHTML = xhr.responseText;` ?

Answer (score 0):

With your statement

```
comment.item(0) = xhr.responseText;
```

you try to give the variable comment.item[0] the responseText as a value.
What you *try* to do, is give the innerHTML of that item the responseText as a value:

```
comment.item(0).innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```